# Getting multiple integer values in an SSRS parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How do I get multiple integers into the value field of an SSRS parameter so that I can use an IN statement in my WHERE clause?

Bear with me. I think this will end up as a simple syntax question but the explanation is overlong.

I have a report that I want to split between two types of staff Dedicated and Bureau. The only way to determine which is which is the hour that the activation occurs, with the dedicated staff working all hours except 12 and 13 (midday to 2pm).

I've created a parameter called @AgentType and added a where clause in my SQL query

```
Where

[Hour] in (@AgentType)
```

I then set the data type of the parameter as an Integer and set the available values as in the picture.
[image: settings]

This works perfectly as a test however if I try to model the working hours accurately

[image]

SSRS removes my commas and turns the interger into 1234567... Also I tried using an expresion =1,2,3... but that caused errors when the report ran.

So my question basically is **how do I get multiple integers into the value field of an SSRS parameter so that I can use an IN statement in my WHERE clause?**

Comment: If you want to use this method, the parameter should be a string and you'll need to change the [HOUR] field to a string as well to allow it to be comparable. I'm sure there's something that needs to be done with the parameter field to get it to recognise the fact it's an array as well...

Comment: It has to be a string.

Comment: @Gallus if I use the "text" option I get this error when running the report             Cannot read the next data row for the dataset DataSet1. (rsErrorReadingNextDataRow)
----------------------------
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution could work for you. You can create two parameters, `AgentType` and `AgentTypeHidden`.

For `AgentType` set two available values as follows:

[image]

`AgentTypeHidden` must be hidden and set to allow multiple values:

[image]

Don't set any available values but default values using this expression:

```
=IIF(
   Parameters!AgentType.Value=1,
   SPLIT("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,14",","),
   SPLIT("12,13",",")
)
```

Also set `Always Refresh` for the `AgentTypeHidden` parameter.

[image]

Finally in your query use the `AgenTypeHidden` parameter.

```
Where [Hour] in (@AgentTypeHidden)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This looks really good. Will it have much of an impact on the run time of the report?

Comment: @tomdemaine, I don't think so since the expression to populate the hidden parameter is basic. You should be careful about the data retrieval, maybe Dedicated option returns a large amount of rows that could affect the performance.

Comment: weirdly the dedicated option runs super fast but the bureau just shows the loading spinner until it times out. edit: it just finished running but the bureau was 1-2 mins slower than the dedicated.

Comment: @tomdemaine, try running your query in SSMS with Dedicated and Bureau values in WHERE clause to see the execution time. Also if you are querying a transactional DB with multiple connections concurrently you could get poor perfomance depending on hardware, server settings, network, even your query, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

I used a simpler solution,
leave the parameter as text, pass it to it eg: 1,2,3,4,5,6
then in the query do the following:

PT-BR

usei uma solução mais simples,
deixe o parâmetro como texto, passe para ele ex: 1,2,3,4,5,6
depois na query faça o seguinte:

```
Where [Hour] in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AgentType, ','))
```