# Excel column of integers pasted in SSRS parameter as comma separated id's

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a column in an Excel-spreadsheet with a hole bunch of numbers of datatype INT. Now I want to run a report in SSRS with these numbers as the parameter (@StackIds). Is there a way to simply paste them in the parameter and they are automatically comma separated? 
I know this should be some sort of function in my WHERE clause in the query but I'm not really advanced in SQL to be writing functions like this. I'm using SSMS to write the query.
Thanks in advance.

Below you can see the columns with the Stackid's from the Exel-spreadsheet. I simply want to copy this entire column and paste them into the inputfield of my ssrs parameter but this parameter is a VARCHAR so they should be comma-separated.

[image: This is the column with StackIds]

[image: SSRS-parameter]

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.   Can you illustrate with some screenshots?

Comment: Show the query you are trying to use. Sample data and expected results would be a good start as well.

Comment: Also, define `a hole bunch of numbers of datatype INT`

Comment: I edited the original post.

Comment: if you enter them manually into the parameter as comma separated, what do you get?

Comment: Then it works, but the fact is that it can be hundreds of numbers. So it would be nice to just paste the numbers and that a function will automatically put commas between the numbers.

Comment: if I understand your question correctly I think this question should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39638047/getting-multiple-integer-values-in-an-ssrs-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sepuic has a good answer, and to directly answer your question about pasting and automatically selecting multiple items

**No,** I'm afraid this is not possible in the usual SSRS UI. You could always write your own web application to wrap SSRS services and parse a single input to select multiple in the called report.

Answer (score 1):

You can load your Excel in SQL Server table using Import/Export Wizard (you can even save the SSIS package locally on your disk and launch it in future just rewriting the Excel file)

Then launch the code like this (here dbo.Nums is the table if integers with the column n):

```
select stuff(( select top 5 ',' + cast(n as varchar(10))  as 'text()'  from dbo.nums for xml path('') ), 1, 1, '');
```

Then copy+paste the result in your report